# How to auto-fill cells next to the ones with the same value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to translate 1000s of cells of text. Some of them are duplicated. How can I easily auto-translate cells with the same value if they appeared earlier. Here is an example:
[image: image example of this]

As you can see some cells are duplicated. How can other cells with the same value auto-fill when I translate the first one?

The important thing is that I can't change the order of cells, so sorting is not an option :(

I kindly appreciate any help with this. Thank you

Comment: This is the quickest way I do it now: 1. go to conditional formatting, 2. Highlight Cells... 3. Duplicates. When I have duplicates highlighted, then I know that when I translate a specific one, I can use search option to find a duplicate and copy-paste the translation. Unfortunately it still takes time, but this is the best solution I've managed to find. Still looking to automate it a bit more. I have thousands of lines to translate and the copy is much longer than just a simple "dog" or "cat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use index/match to solve the issue. In the example below I have entered the translation for the first Cat and Dog, then entered the following formula in field B4 and pulled it down:

> =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A4,A4)=1,"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A4,A:A,0)))

[image]

If I overwrite the formula in field B5 with the word "Maus", then Maus also gets populated in field B9:

[image]

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: Just curious - does this work the same as the `Vlookup()` I posted, or are there practical differences/benefits with the index/match?

Comment: Yes, index/match and vlookup basically provide the same results, but I feel index/match is easier to apply because I don't like to use the column reference.

Answer (score 1):

Post this code in cell C2 and then drag the formula down as far as you need. As you fill in the details into column B you will see the cells populate with the translation if there's a previous instance.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A9,A9)>1,INDEX($B$2:B8,MATCH(A9,$A$2:A9,0)),"")
```

Comment: I see VBA Pete beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Vlookup()` with `IfError()` to hide errors.

In `B3`, `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$A$2:B2,2,TRUE),"")` and drag down.